# webView не отображает определенный сайт

Tags: ios, swift, webview

Создал я себе **webView** на отдельном контроллере, начала проверять сайты и один сайт почему то ни в какую не хочет загружаться. Просто пустой экран, хотя остальные три работают и загружаются.

```
class WebViewViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url5 = URL(string: "https://sunlightstudio.ru")
        let url3 = URL(string: "https://www.yandex.ru")
        let url2 = URL(string: "https://www.cross-studio.ru")
        let url = URL (string: "https://www.google.com")
        let url4 = URL(string: "https://www.vk.com")
        let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url2!)
        self.webView?.load(requestObj)
    }
}
```

Неработает почему то **url2**. С чем может быть проблема?
Пробовал варианты:

http://cross-studio.ru

http://www.cross-studio.ru

https://cross-studio.ru

https://www.cross-studio.ru

**Info.plist** (кто-то просил добавить), не знаю в каком виде его добавлять, добавлю пока в таком виде
[image: info.plist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в `Info.plist`

Новую строку `App Transport Security Settings`

Внутри этой строки добавье параметр `Allow Arbitrary Loads` со значением `YES`
 Должно получиться как на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после чего попробуйте загрузить этот url http://cross-studio.ru

Comment: Сработало, спасибо)